# Inherit permissions from parent to child site page in Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-dxp

Is there any solution to inherit permissions from parent site page to child site page in Liferay?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can [add a Page Template](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/7-0/creating-pages-from-templates), configure its permissions, and use it for all your pages? That way child pages have the same permissions as parent pages.